# Why doesn't PresentViewControllerAsync block?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Code:

```
await vc.PresentViewControllerAsync(otherVC, true);
someMethod();
```

I would expect this to wait until the presented `otherVC` exits. That's why the last argument of the non async version is missing, right? Because it's supposed to be `someMethod`. But in fact, the above code just shows `otherVC` and immediately runs `someMethod`.

If it's ***not*** supposed to block - why even have it? Why not have only `PresentViewController`?

Comment: @OmarHimada That is incorrect.

Comment: @ispiro If you wish to create a "blocking/waiting" situation, use the `PresentViewController` followed by a event handle wait (ex: ManualResetEvent)  and in the PresentViewController completion block release the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the docs (I don't use Xamarin):

`PresentViewControllerAsync` would present a view controller **asynchronously** -- meaning, it would NOT block, and the next line will execute ***while*** otherVC is *being presented*.

`PresentViewController` has a completion handler -- meaning, otherVC will be ***presented*** and ***then*** the completion block will run. (Note, the completion block will run after the *presentation* of the VC is finished... ***not*** after the presented VC is dismissed).

Comment: That's a good point. Still useless, but maybe that _is_ what they meant. +1.

Answer (score 0):

**PresentViewControllerAsync** is a `Asynchronous` method . Generally ,it appears in a task method , lastly you want to back to UI thread to present view controller . If not in a task method , you will not need to use it. **In short**, if you need to call the UI's method of the present view controller in the method of the task, Xamarin provides such a simple method.

> If it's not supposed to block - why even have it? Why not have only PresentViewController?

About the doubt , I think maybe you just want to know where need to use this metbod . I want to say that this method sometimes will be used in Xamarin Forms when using Custom renderer to invoking native method .

For example , if want to Share Dialog with Xamarin Forms ,to activate the in-built share dialog, we need to implement this on each platform. First, lets create an interface, so we can call this from our portable library.

```
public interface IShare
{
    Task Show(string title, string message, string filePath);
}
```

Then **iOS** calls this an Activity View. Create a UIActivityViewController, fill with the relevant details and display.

```
public class Share : IShare
{
    // MUST BE CALLED FROM THE UI THREAD
    public async Task Show(string title, string message, string filePath)
    {
        var items = new NSObject[] { NSObject.FromObject(title), NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath) };
    var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(items, null);
    var vc = GetVisibleViewController();

    NSString[] excludedActivityTypes = null;

    if (excludedActivityTypes != null && excludedActivityTypes.Length > 0)
        activityController.ExcludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes;

    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
    {
        if (activityController.PopoverPresentationController != null)
        {
            activityController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = vc.View;
        }
    }
    await vc.PresentViewControllerAsync(activityController, true);      
    }

    UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
    {
        var rootController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

    if (rootController.PresentedViewController == null)
        return rootController;

    if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UINavigationController)
    {
        return ((UINavigationController)rootController.PresentedViewController).TopViewController;
    }

    if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UITabBarController)
    {
            return ((UITabBarController)rootController.PresentedViewController).SelectedViewController;
    }

    return rootController.PresentedViewController;
    }
}
```

Now here you can see that Controller must be called from UI task ,so need async method to invoke it. That is just my understanding about it , if later other people give more points , that will be better.

**In addition**:

If want to first run present , then run somemethod . Maybe you can try this method :

**[UIViewController.PresentViewController(UIViewController, Boolean, Action)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiviewcontroller.presentviewcontroller?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(UIKit.UIViewController.PresentViewController);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Xamarin.iOS,Version%3Dv1.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)**

It has a Completion action to execute after the presentation finishes.

Used as follow :

```
this.PresentViewController(new UIViewController(), true, () => {
    SomeMethod();
});
```